# bitcoin transfer without creating wallet

Tags: blockchain, client, bip32-hd-wallets, android, blockcypher

My question is about transferring bitcoin between two addresses without having a wallet.

Here is my idea of transferring bitcoins in following way:

**Idea:**

I have my own Android Application. I am willing to send/receive bitcoin using [blockcypher Apis](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin)

I will keep private and public keys generated from above apis in my own database by encrypting it.

**Does it make sense?**

This might be a stupid question to experts, but as a newbie in block-chain technology I am curious to know the right direction of the concept.

Comment: Essentially, it seems to me, what you are writing is what most would call "a wallet."   A wallet is a system that keeps and manages bitcoin addresses (public keys) with their corresponding private keys. A wallet also knows and displays the total number of unspent coins it holds .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this would work.

That said, you are essentially building your own wallet - A wallet is simply a program that hold private keys, keeps track of spendable inputs, and signs transactions.

Your system achieves all of the above, so you are essentially building your own wallet.